# Как в Canvas определить объект касанием?

Tags: android, kotlin, view, android-canvas

В Canvas нарисовал квадрат и на углах расположил круги, они служат как кнопки, с помощью которых можно менять размеры фигуры, методом перетаскивания.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если я укажу координаты нижнего угла `x1`, `y2`, то вряд ли смогу попасть в него с первого касания, тогда нужна некая рамка как изображено на картинке, с условием, если касание было в пределах рамки, можно изменять размер.

Но как добиться этого? Мне пришла в голову такая идея, но мне кажется есть проще.

```
if ((x > x1-max  && x < x1+max && y > y2-max && y < y2+max) && touchActive) {
        x1 = event!!.x
        touchActive = false
        invalidate()
    } else{
        touchActive = true
    }
```

Читая этот код, вы надолго задумываетесь, и если мне необходимо переделать логику, это нужно столько условий дописать, что не всегда в голове получается удержать.

**Дополнил ответ.**

```
class ExampleRect(context: Context, att : AttributeSet) : View(context, att) {

    private val rect : RectF = RectF()

    val p = Paint().apply {
        color = Color.DKGRAY
        strokeWidth = 10f
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)

        rect.set(400f, 40f, 40f, 400f)

        canvas?.apply {
            drawRect(rect, p)
        }
    }

    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {

        println("click -> ${rect.contains(event!!.x, event.y)}")

        return true
    }

}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот что получилось.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно вот так:

```
if (Math.abs(centerX - x) < distance && Math.abs(centerY - y) < distance) {
    //hit 
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, этот вариант я считаю универсальным, так как если создавать объекты через класс canvas, у меня не будет возможности вызвать метод `contains`, а создавать еще один объект `Rect()` не всегда за хочется.

Comment: Вы не в курсе, как мне в canvas сгенерировать еще такую же фигуру, со всеми возможностями, то есть клонировать его.

Comment: Не совсем понял какую фигуру? Еще есть несколько дополнений к вашему коду, вам не нужно делать apply, вы можете сразу написать   canvas?.drawRect(rect, p). И в примере кода вы задали с помощью rect просто точку, у вас кординаты ->  х(лево) : 400, у(верх):40, x(право):400, y(низ): 40, поэтому метод contains проверят попадание именно в эту точку.

Comment: Ту которую я нарисовал на картинке, у нее есть логика реагирования на касание. Вот мне бы хотелось как-то сохранить всё это в виде объекта, после чего в новом `View` создать иконку которая будет вызывать (клонировать) ранее созданный объект и отображать в canvas. Если сложно понять, представьте Paint, там есть готовые фигуры.

Comment: В комментарии выше я не правильно написал про точку если что :) Если я правильно понял, то вам как раз и нужно просто описать это логику во вью (ExampleRect), а потом вы просто будете использовать свою ExampleRect. в верстке или добавлять через код. НО, у вас сейчас координаты отрисовки rect задана хардкором, а должны задаваться в зависимости от размеров вашего view.  https://medium.com/mindorks/android-custom-views-tutorial-part-1-115fa8d53be5

Comment: Это будет похоже на Paint, который умеет генерировать фигуры. Если вы в Paint нарисуете квадрат, то он вам предложить возможность переместить или изменить его вид, я могу предположить, что в этой фигуре уже есть логика которая это позволяет делать. Я хочу тоже самое. Я попытался это изобразить на картинке.

Comment: Проблема в том, что, да, я создал вью, в котором нарисовал квадрат, описал логику и отобразил это в верстке, а хотелось как в Paint, в одном окне, на холсте рисовать

Comment: Понимаешь тут есть вопрос логики, должна ли View уметь клонировать сама себя и передвигать? Я думаю что правильнее будет так, ты выносишь всю логику связанную с твоим квадратом и касаниями на него в свою ExampleRect, а по нажатию на кнопку ты будешь добавлять новый ExamleRect на экран и передвигать его. Понимаешь что если в одном классе будет инкапсулирована логика создания нескольких твоих квадратов, то тебе придется еще и следить за ними всеми в одном классе, что как раз и приводит к выводу о том что не стоит так делать.

Comment: Да, я об этому думал, и в этом и была проблема, за одним следить еще можно, а когда их много, тут уже генерация имен видать нужна. Я попробую первый вариант. Потом отпишуть.

Comment: Получилось, даже не плохо, прям как в Paint. Еще нужно будет подумать, как редактировать предыдущие фигуры, а так класс. Спасибо. Я добавлю изображение.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно создать вокруг точек углов прямоугольники Rect (или RectF) и проверять произошло ли касание в одном из этих прямоугольников методом `Rect.contains(float x , float y)`

Comment: Всё сделал, но почему то не работает, всегда выдает false. Делал так, создал глобальную переменную `private val rect : RectF = RectF()` в методе `onDraw` нарисовал, а в методе `onTouchEvent` вызываю `println(" click - ${rect.contains(x, y)}")`

Comment: Приведи полностью код с заданием значений Rect. И тебе его рисовать не нужно (если ты не хочешь конечно чтоб он отображался).

Comment: @yno7 Я дополнил ответ.